# Bing maps ajax control 7.0 polygon fillColor in IE8

Tags: bing-maps

In internet explorer 8, none of my polygons on my bing maps have the proper fill color. They are always filled in white. I have no issues in firefox, chrome, safari or opera.

I've even tried using the exact code from the bing docs

```
// Initialize the map
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {credentials:"Bing Maps Key"}); 

// Create the locations
var location1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(20,-20);
var location2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(20,20);
var location3 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-20,20);
var location4 = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-20,-20);


// Create a polygon 
var vertices = new Array(location1, location2, location3, location4, location1);
var polygoncolor = new Microsoft.Maps.Color(100,100,0,100);
var polygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(vertices,{fillColor: polygoncolor, strokeColor: polygoncolor});

// Add the shape to the map
map.entities.push(polygon)

// Set the view
map.setView({bounds: Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(vertices)});
```

Has anyone experienced this?

I am also using jquery 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

I was using a htc file (ie-css3.htc) for some css3 effects in IE. I guess this doesn't play nicely with bing maps polygon colors.